# CSS sheet not linking in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

For IE and Chrome, I am having no problems with CSS, however when I open my page on Firefox, none of the CSS effects are working. Not sure which part of the code I should post, but here is my link element

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\Jaesung\Desktop\Web Pages\finit style sheet.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
```

Comment: You need at least to provide the version of the firefox and the css version you are using.

Comment: try removing space from the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use file paths in `href` attributes, support for them across browsers is inconsistent. Use URLs.

If you want them to work on your local file system (instead of installing a webserver for development), then use relative URLs.

```
href="finit%20style%20sheet.css"
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm only doing this for testing, and I have no clue how web servers work yet.